# MySQL Cannot Compare TEXT

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table called `table_1` that has column named `col_1` of type `TEXT`. I am trying query a row that has a certain value using this statement, but no data is returned.

`SELECT * FROM table _1 WHERE col_1 = '1325'`

However, when I used this statement, I do get data.

`SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE col_1 LIKE '%1325%'`

How do I get the first statement to work?

Comment: The column must contain something else in addition to `1325`. `LIKE` matches the string anywhere in the value, `=` matches the whole thing exactly.

Comment: What does `SELECT LENGTH(col_1) FROM table_1 WHERE col_1 LIKE '%1325%'` return? I'll bet it's something more than `4`.

Comment: there might be some spaces with the text 1325 that is why your first query is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the select with the `WHERE col_1 LIKE '%1325%'` brings back a value that looks like `1325`, but then `WHERE col_1 = '1325'` doesn't?

Then it's probably because of invisible characters.

For example if the value of col_1 is '1325 '.
Because of the extra space, that value isn't equal to '1325'.
But it does contain '1325', so the LIKE would find it.
It's easy not to notice what's not visible.

What you could do is [TRIM](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-trim-function.php) the value, so that spaces are removed before comparing it with `=`.

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE TRIM(col_1) = '1325';
```

Note that a default TRIM or [RTRIM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_rtrim) removes only the spaces.
To make that work for other whitespace characters the SQL becomes be a bit longer.

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 
WHERE TRIM(Replace(Replace(Replace(col_1,'\t',''),'\n',''),'\r','')) = '1325';
```

And if you want to have visual evidence wether this is caused by invisible whitespaces?
Then use the `LIKE`, and `CONCAT` something to the start and end of the column. Then the spaces will be easy to notice in the result.

```
select CONCAT('[',col_1,']') AS Test, t.* from table_1 t where col_1 like '%1325%';
```

You can test it [here](http://rextester.com/CIRY8194)

Comment: How odd, I found out that my string was enclosed in single quote characters for some reason because I generated the table with Python. You did not figure out the problem, but your answer helped me think of what was wrong, so you still get best answer.

Comment: @JoeMark Ah I see. Glad it helped you then. :) Well, so in the end it wasn't something that someone could have guessed just from the question about sql alone.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that the quotes around the text were just showing it was a string, I did not think the quotes were actually part of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Because you do not test with:
 - **SELECT * FROM table _1 WHERE col_1="1325" **

Answer (score -2):

the second statment means the data contains 1325 but you don't have a row containning 13
Hope you got iT thanks

Comment: that is not the correct answer, please explain it in a proper way.

Comment: I mean if He have 2 rows one is 1325 and other is 13251 
when he will make Select * from table_1 where col_1 like '%1325%' it will get both . if the first stament is not getting back rows that means there is no row containning just 1325 that what i mean